# chrome-extension:// links open about:blank

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've recently been contributing to the Enhanced Steam extension and I've found that a link fetched with chrome.extension.getURL simply opens about:blank and not the link described.

I do not believe it's actually a problem with the extension, but rather a problem in chrome. The link it supplies is valid (chrome-extension://pimjhgjngccknempdnehdeaihcjbajod/options.html) and navigating directly works correctly.

I tried chrome.tabs.create, but found that I am not allowed to use it due to the script modifying pre-existing content.

Any help or work arounds would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is. I also wonder what this sentence means: "I tried chrome.tabs.create, but found that I am not allowed to use it due to the script modifying pre-existing content."

Comment: It is a web_accessible_resource, as described above I get the URL using chrome.

The page just simply opens about:blank instead of the actual desired link.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Links to background pages now open about:blank for some reason.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk: Please, post the relevant code.

Comment: `window.location.href = "chrome-extension://pimjhgjngccknempdnehdeaihcjbajod/options.html";`. An anchor tag click produces the same result.

Comment: `<a class="popup_menu_item" target="_blank" href="chrome-extension://pimjhgjngccknempdnehdeaihcjbajod/options.html">Options</a>`


I have the element shown above inserted into a page that the extension interacts with. When I click upon the element, the page `about:blank` opens, but no page actually opens, like it should.

I tried the way @JoshBjelovuk was doing it, that too opens `about:blank`

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk, Smashman: I cannot reproduce it (using Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on Windows). What Chrome version/OS are you on ?

Comment: Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m

Windows 7.

http://smash.mn/s/1384974973.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put all my required files into `"web_accessible_resources"`, it solved my problem. See this in #4 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310870#c4

It is Chrome's previous problem which is not secure. In build 31.0.1650.57, Chrome fixed this which is to force to put required files in `"web_accessible_resources"`. In Chrome extension, lots of [samples](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html) don't use `"web_accessible_resources"`, those are the bugs, those samples will have this "chrome-extension:// links open about:blank" problem in build 31.0.1650.57.

Actually my chrome extension [MarkView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markview/iaddkimmopgchbbnmfmdcophmlnghkim) was facing this issue and I had to update its `manifest.json` to make it work for this Chrome update. By the way, MarkView is tool to read and write Awesome Markdown Files, it provides features including Content Outline, Sortable Tables and code block syntax highlight with line number.

Comment: See now I feel silly. I did think it was in `web_accessible_resources`, but it turns out that it was not. Appending it to my already sizeable list fixed the problem.

Comment: Just in case if people have interesting on Chrome new update about Fixed the security issues on version 36.0.1985.125

Chrome 36.0.1985.125 WEDNESDAY, JULY 16, 2014. I wrote a post for one fixed issue, here is the [link](http://www.shaneweng.com/blog/Close-Popup-Window-in-Chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in Chrome to me. If you don't have too many pages like this to change then could you try using message passing to pass the page you want to open to the background page? Then use either window.open or chrome.tabs.create within the background page. Example code shown below:

```
//CONTENT SCRIPT

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "OpenPage", filename:"somepage.html", querystring:"?aValue="+someVal}, function(response) {});
```

Then in your Background page

```
//BACKGROUND PAGE

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {  
 if (request.greeting == "OpenPage"){
  open_page(request.filename, request.querystring)
 }

  });


function open_page(filename, querystring){

var pageUrl = chrome.extension.getURL(filename)+querystring;

chrome.tabs.create({'url': pageUrl }, function(tab) {
  // Tab opened.
});
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a background page.

I read about Event Pages, but I wasn't sure if it was worth it.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I have been searching everywhere for a way around the about:blank and this worked. Thanks again!